# What is the google cloud product that is like firebase hosting?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform

For every product in firebase, there is a product in google cloud that does the same thing but with more capabilities. For example, there is firebase storage and google cloud storage, firebase functions and google cloud functions and so..., what about firebase hosting, what is the google cloud product of it ?

Comment: Maybe you are looking for Google App Engine https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs?hl=en-419

Comment: No, app engine is for hosting my backend. firebase hosting is for hosting front-end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to host static files on Google Cloud Platform without using Firebase, you can either use [App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/getting-started/hosting-a-static-website) (which is a common solution for this even when you don't have backend code) or [Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website).

---

> For every product in firebase, there is a product in google cloud that does the same thing but with more capabilities.

Some products in Firebase may be based on, or repackaged from, Google Cloud Platform products, but there are more of them that are not. Remote Config, A/B Testing, Dynamic Links, Predictions, App Distribution, In-App Messaging, to name a few.

For example: Firebase Hosting does not use Cloud Storage for its hosting, but uses a 3rd party CDN for the delivery. While Firebase Hosting *does* use Cloud Storage for some of its internal infrastructure, it is in no way a less capable version of Cloud Storage. In fact, if you use Cloud Storage to host your static web site, you'll miss out on the much more powerful CDN that Firebase Hosting uses.

Comment: So, I have an app, that is made with `angular` for front end, and `djanjo + postgreSQL` for backend.I am going to use `firebase hosting` for angular front end, and `compute engine` for djanjo backend. Is that how I should do it ? Or the whole website can be deployed only using compute engine ?

Comment: @ahmedosama You can deploy the whole site on compute engine. However, I think you can utilise app-engine for deploying both backend and frontend, with your postgres on cloudSql (Or use cloud datastore, if you're not using any RDBMS specific feature).

Comment: App engine is really expensive compared to compute engine or kubernates egnine. I prefer to manage the app infrastructure myself to save some money. but I am just trying to figure out what google cloud products I will be using for deployment. I don't want to use cloud datastore or firestore, I am good with postgresql. Additionally, they are much more expensive. Simply, I want to reduce cost as much as possible.